# Dynamic inner html event not working in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, events, click, innerhtml

These are my code

child.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() dataFromParent: String;
  @Output() sendDataToParent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  htmldata:any;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.htmldata = '<input type="text" #data><button (click)="_sendDataToParent(data.value)">Send event to parent</button>';

    console.log('This is data from parents', this.dataFromParent);
    console.log('this.htmldata', this.htmldata);
  }

  _sendDataToParent(data:string) {
    console.log('you clicked');
    this.sendDataToParent.emit(data);
  }

  makeSanitize(str: any)
  {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(str);
  }
}
```

child.component.html

```
<h2>Child Component</h2>
<p>{{dataFromParent}}</p>
<span [innerHTML]="makeSanitize(htmldata)"></span>
```

app.component.html

```
<h2>Parent Component</h2>
<p>
    {{dataFromChild}}
</p>

<hr>
<hr>
<hr>

<child-component 
  [dataFromParent]="'This is data sent from parent'"
  (sendDataToParent)="eventFromChild($event)">
</child-component>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  dataFromChild;
  eventFromChild(data) {
    console.log(data);
    this.dataFromChild = data;
  }
}
```

I planned to generate `htmldata` dynamically.

`htmldata` has innerhtml values in its child component. Innerhtml also have Click event which is not working.

I want to fill the input and click the `Send event to parent` button. But the event was not triggered.

Dear developers please help me

Comment: Friends please anyone guide me

Answer (score 1):

You are coding "angular" in a string value and then putting it into the DOM.
The angular code needs to be compiled to be transformed in real html/js code

Thus you need to start by writing "onclick" instead of "(click)"
But then you will have other error like "_sendDataToParent is not defined" because you would need that function a "script" tag

See here to test https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4s9fzs

In the end, producing angular code in a string and then putting it into the DOM is probably something you don't want to do

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting error like this when I type input text and click send to parent button ```Error occurred (1:1)
_sendDataToParent is not defined```

Comment: Yes as stated in my comment, you would need other changes to make it work because it's not angular anymore but plain html
Answer : "But then you will have other error like "_sendDataToParent is not defined" because **you would need that function in a "script" tag**"

Comment: Sorry, It is not what i am exactly seeking for. I want pass some arguments via this function also. Is there anyway to make it work using "click" instead of "onclick"